# pulling a value by comparing 2 lists

Tags: apex, map, list

```
Map<String, Case> objMap1 = new Map<String, Case>();

Map<String, Imp__c> objMap2 = new Map<String, Imp__c>();

List<Case> nwCase = [SELECT SID__c FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'Web' and RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Imp'];

for(Case p : nwCase)

{

    objMap1.put(p.SID__c, p);

    }

List<Imp__c> mp = [SELECT Actual_Status__c, Actual_ID__c FROM Imp__c WHERE Actual_ID__c != null];

for(Imp__c e : mp)
{
    objMap2.put(e.Actual_ID__c, e);

}  

for(Case c: nwCase){

          if(objMap2.containsKey(c.SID__c)){

          // how to get the Status of the above c.SID__c from Imp__c here?
          // i.e, the Actual_Status__c of c.SID__c
```

Appreciate your help!!!

- Don't know why Map(String, Case) is not getting pasted correctly above!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly consider using more appropriate variable naming conventions. Your fellow developers will thank you later.

```
for(Case c: nwCase){

      if(objMap2.containsKey(c.SID__c)){

      // how to get the Status of the above c.SID__c from Imp__c here?
      // i.e, the Actual_Status__c of c.SID__c

      // Get the Imp__c record from the objMap2 map related to this case
      Imp__c theImp = objMap2.get(c.SID__c);
      system.debug('Actual_Status__c of c.SID__c is: ' + theImp.Actual_Status__c);
```